# Script to configure perfmon counters

Tags: vbscript, scripting

I need to write a script to configure PERFMON counters on server. I want to write the same in VBS. Please help with some example or reference. I need to configure the below counters

```
"\Memory\Available MBytes"
"\Memory\Pool Nonpaged Bytes"
"\Memory\Pool Paged Bytes"
"\PhysicalDisk(*)\Current Disk Queue Length"
"\PhysicalDisk(*)\Disk Reads/sec"
"\PhysicalDisk(*)\Disk Reads Bytes/sec"
"\PhysicalDisk(*)\Disk Writes/sec"
"\PhysicalDisk(*)\Disk Writes Bytes/sec"
"\Process(*)\% Processor Time"
"\Process(*)\Private Bytes
"\Process(*)\Virtual Bytes"
```

Comment: Configure the counters for what? Where? What have you tried so far?

Comment: I have tried writing an poweshell but won't work. I want to automate the steps to configure perfmon counters on windows server.

Answer (score 1):

I followed the below reference and its working good

http://geekswithblogs.net/RobBowman/archive/2009/07/08/scripting-perfmon.aspx